# Use Python String with HTML

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Say I have some string in a python file like:

```
myString = "Hello StackOverflow"
```

How I could access and use it in a separate html file like this generic template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use one of the many existing template libraries (Jinja being one of the most popular).

You can simply read in your template as a string and `.format()` it like any other, but this is error prone and you will run into many difficulties.

- http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/
- https://www.makotemplates.org/
- https://genshi.edgewall.org/